# My optaplanner solution doesn't improve shortly after the solve started. How do I debug this?

Tags: debugging, logging, output, optaplanner

Shortly after my solution started being solved, I get exactly one update of the initial score (from -54init/0hard/0medium/-33275soft to 0hard/0medium/-34035soft), after which nothing else moves (the examples-like UI still shows the "Solving ..." and the orange waves in the right hand corner)

So I looked for more debugging output (which didn't succeed for still unknown reasons), in an attempt to determine whether no further steps are executed, or if the steps just don't result into any better result (as far as I think, there should be improvements in the score). What makes it a little more puzzling, is the uncertainty if I properly deepcloned a problem fact's one class - maybe what I'm seeing is a sign of not having done it properly ?

So now I'm rather stuck in my options, mostly lacking experience working with Optaplanner (which I definitely want to get to know better). I know this is a rather basic Optaplanner question, but could someone with slightly more working experience with Optaplanner give me a clue about my further debug possibilities ? I would already be happy if I could have more debug output similar to what's happening in the examples (e.g., where should my logback.xml be put) ?

Comment: What happens if your turn on enviromnentMode FULL_ASSERT (which slows down everything)? Does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't fail : the behaviour remains as it was without that environment mode. That is : the solver keeps on stepping through always other alternatives, only the score doesn't improve. What can I deduct from this ?Now, I have to say ("admit" ?) this is (still) a simple problem. There may just not be a better solution. Commenting out one constraint resulted in the same behaviour, only the constraint result was stuck on another value (and remained with that value just like now)

Comment: I found out that the score is not corrupted. Unfortunately (?!), it's not because of me not corrupting it : it's because of a shadow variable not being updated (and staying at a value of 0 and hence not being counted properly in the related constraint's penalize()- calculation). Still finding out why :/

Comment: Which algorithm do you use in local search phase? I had similiar problem with simulated annealing but not with tabu search. Also after some 15 minutes the solution started to change again with simulated annealing. So how long did you run the algorithm?

Comment: TABU_SEARCH was used here. However, my findings have turned out to be wrong (if you read through everything around here) : I expected to see the moves, but I hadn't seen any. But that finding was wrong, as it was the logging that hadn't been properly setup. So I DID have moves selected, I only didn't get to see them in the log output.
OTOH, it's not impossible, depending on your case, that one local search selection performs a lot better than the other one. Maybe you should have a look at benchmarking your solution with different local search phases.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the debug information : I found out that the missing maven recipe to have debug logging output similar to the examples, is the following :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So after having added that recipe, I got the proper debug logging like in the examples (the logback.xml file, copied from the examples, had been correctly placed in the resources folder)

The debug output furthermore shows that the solver is stepping properly through the possibilities. So I'll have to start debugging the constraints ...

Comment: Yes, turn on `TRACE` or `DEBUG` logging to see the choices optaplanner makes.

Comment: Yes, I had been after this useful information (now with success after some initial problems, as you noticed)